# Keras model checkpoint is not tracking val_loss from previous runs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Every time I restart training from a checkpoint, I get the following:

`val_root_mean_squared_error improved from inf to 0.38011`

When what I expected to get was (examples):

`Epoch 1: val_root_mean_squared_error improved from 0.583 to 0.38011`

or

`Epoch 1: val_root_mean_squared_error did not improve from 0.326`

I'm afraid that my model is getting overwritten. Here is my checkpoint:

```
checkpoint_filepath = f'{log_location}/mdl.ckpt'    

checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_filepath,
    save_weights_only=False,
    monitor=monitor,
    mode=mode,
    verbose=0,
    save_best_only=True)

if os.path.isdir(checkpoint_filepath):
    print(f'loading model from {checkpoint_filepath}')
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(checkpoint_filepath, custom_objects={'loss_fcn': loss_fcn})

model.fit(X_train,
            y_train,
            batch_size=params['batch_size'],
            epochs=epochs,
            shuffle=True,
            validation_data=(X_val, y_val),
            callbacks=[checkpoint, lr_scheduler, tensorboard],
            verbose=1)
```

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

I think this has something to do with it, although I havn't found a solution to fix this error message, and from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/47554), it seems like I should be able to ignore the message.

```
WARNING:absl:Found untraced functions such as lstm_cell_1_layer_call_fn, lstm_cell_1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses, lstm_cell_2_layer_call_fn, lstm_cell_2_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses, lstm_cell_4_layer_call_fn while saving (showing 5 of 8). These functions will not be directly callable after loading.
```

Here is how I build the model (BiLSTM):

```
@tf.function
def loss_fcn(y_t, y_p):

    y_pred = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_p)
    y_true = tf.cast(y_t, y_pred.dtype)

    diff = y_pred-y_true

    res = tf.map_fn(fn=lambda x: tf.math.exp(tf.abs(x)/(3)) - 1 if x < 0 else tf.math.exp(tf.abs(x)/9) - 1, elems=diff)
    s_score = tf.math.reduce_sum(res)

    mse = tf.math.reduce_sum(backend.mean(tf.math.squared_difference(y_pred, y_true), axis=-1))

    return (s_score + mse)  / 2.0



def build_bilstm_model(params, *args, **kwargs):
    """
        @brief: builds the model with the specified params
    """
    i = 0
    
    # input layer
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=params['input_shape'], name='inp1')
    # first layer
    x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(units=params[f'units_{i}'], 
                        recurrent_dropout=params['recurrent_dropout'],
                        kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=params['l1'], l2=params['l2']),
                        return_sequences=True, 
                        name=f'hdn_{0}'), name=f'hdn_a{0}')(inputs)

    if params['dropout_rate'] > 0.0:
        x = layers.Dropout(rate=params['dropout_rate'])(x)

    # subsequent layers
    for i in range(1, params['layers']-1):
        x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(units=params[f'units_{i}'], 
                        recurrent_dropout=params['recurrent_dropout'],
                        kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=params['l1'], l2=params['l2']),
                        return_sequences=True, 
                        name=f'hdn_{i}'), name=f'hdn_{i}')(x)

        if params['dropout_rate'] > 0.0:
            x = layers.Dropout(rate=params['dropout_rate'])(x)

    # last layers
    x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(units=params[f'units_{i+1}'], 
                        recurrent_dropout=params['recurrent_dropout'],
                        kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=params['l1'], l2=params['l2']),
                        return_sequences=False, 
                        name=f'hdn_{i+1}'), name=f'hdn_{i+1}')(x)

    if params['dropout_rate'] > 0.0:
        x = layers.Dropout(rate=params['dropout_rate'])(x)     

    # output layer
    outputs = layers.Dense(params['num_outputs'])(x)

    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    # compile
    model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=params['learning_rate']),
                  loss=loss_fcn,#'mse',
                  metrics=[keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])
    print("returning model")
    return model
```

These are the model parameters:

```
params = {
  "layers": 2,
  "units_0": 80, #80
  "dropout_rate": 0.2,
  "l1": 1e-05,
  "l2": 0.0001,
  "learning_rate": 0.0015,
  "recurrent_dropout": 0.0,
  "batch_size": 64,
  "units_1": 60, #60
  "input_shape": (None, len(features)),
  "num_outputs": 1,
  "trial": 'explain'
}
```

Comment: How did you define `checkpoint_best_filepath`?

Comment: Why you have two checkpoints in your callbacks?

Comment: I have 2 checkpoints because one checkpoint I want to keep the best, and the other checkpoint I want to keep the current. I have updated the code to show just the one checkpoint, as the other checkpoint isn't relevant to this question.

Comment: You are loading custom loss object but I don't see you saving it.

Comment: You don't save the model with the custom loss function, only load it. At least this is what I know - please point me to a reference is this is not the case.